# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Even after setting the -Xms1024m ,-Xmx4096m,-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit in sts configuration file, I am still getting the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in Spring Tool Suite
Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this error..

Comment: if your STS installation is repeatedly running out of memory, you should capture a heap dump when it throws that error (add -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to the end of your sts.ini file) and make it available to us for further analysis. Please upload it somewhere and file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide that points to the heap dump. You could also send us a link privately, if you don't want to share the heap dump publicly. Then we can dive into the details and figure out what is causing the memory issues.

Comment: For the bug report it would also be useful to have a few steps how to reproduce the issue (if possible), what system you are running on, which JDK version you use, and which version of STS you are using (and third-party plugins that you installed in addition to the standard STS distribution). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error** is displayed when your application has exhausted pretty much all the available memory and GC has repeatedly failed to clean it.

if you just wished to get rid of the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded” message, adding the following to your startup scripts would achieve just that:

```
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Comment: But it probably won't help since the problem is likely that there is no more memory for the JVM to run properly. So it will just be stuck longer before exiting with a slightly different error... won't it?

Comment: @Kris yes. And as you can see I have already used that particluar line, And still I am facing the issue.